# JavaFX CSS: add inner shadow to a pane itself

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8

My CSS is:

```
.hollow {
    -fx-background-color: #dddddd;
    -fx-effect: innershadow( gaussian, rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 ), 10, 0, 5, 5 );
}
```

I want to apply this effect to an HBox pane itself, giving it an appropriate CSS class, but instead of this the effect applies to its children (buttons, etc.).

How can I apply the effect only to the pane itself, living aside its children?

**Edited:**

Fixed a typo.

Comment: Just fix the typo: `-fx-background-color`

Comment: Thanks, @James_D, but this does not solve the problem. Both the color and the effect still apply to the children of the pane, not to the pane itself.

Comment: Can you post a simple, complete example? I can only reproduce this if the `-fx-background-color` is not set on the pane (not sure why that is needed, but anyway...)

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me with code in the controller.

```
hBox.setEffect(new InnerShadow(BlurType.THREE_PASS_BOX, Color.GRAY,2,0,0,0));
hBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white");
```

I don`t know why css doesn`t work here.